# php how to make a if str_replace?

Tags: php, str-replace

`$str` is some value in a foreach.

```
$str = str_replace('_name_','_title_',$str);
```

how to make a `if str_replace`?

I want do the thing `if have a str_replace` then echo `$str`, else not, jump the current foreach then to the next. Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is a fourth parameter to [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) that is set to the number of replacements performed. If nothing was replaced, it's set to 0. Drop a reference variable there, and then check it in your if statement:

```
foreach ($str_array as $str) {
    $str = str_replace('_name_', '_title_', $str, $count);

    if ($count > 0) {
        echo $str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need to test whether a string is found within another string, you can like this.

```
<?php
if(strpos('_name_', $str) === false) {
    //String '_name_' is not found
    //Do nothing, or you could change this to do something
} else {
    //String '_name_' found
    //Replacing it with string '_title_'
    $str = str_replace('_name_','_title_',$str);
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

However you shouldn't need to, for this example. If you run `str_replace` on a string that has nothing to replace, it won't find anything to replace, and will just move on without making any replacements or changes.

Good luck.

Comment: strpos has to have the haystack first.

This is correct: (strpos($str, '_name_') === false)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but it gives me a guideline to solve my own checking problem, so my solution was:

```
$contn = "<p>String</p><p></p>";
$contn = str_replace("<p></p>","",$contn,$value);
if ($value==0) {
$contn = nl2br($contn);
}
```

Works perfectly for me.
Hope this is useful to someone else.